# Listview last item ends with weird view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a listview with database data and its working all fine and perfect only lat item view looks like something weird. last item contains shadows at the bottom and i want to remove that shadow then how can i do this. The below image will help you to understand.

[image]

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Inside your XML File. in Listview TAG.

```
   android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
```